# Android scaling of images to screen density

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I have an application with an embedded drawable 48x48 pixel at 71,12 pixels/inch
I load the same image via a stream to a webserver, then load that stream

```
return new BitmapDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), new ByteArrayInputStream(imageThumbnail));
```

the displayed result is:

[image: screenshot]

How can i get the BitmapDrawable to scale the same as the rest of the drawables?

Comment: You mean `BitmapDrawable.setDensity(71);` ?

Comment: There is no setDensity() method in android 2.1 at least, i tried  bitmapDrawable.setTargetDensity(getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); but it yielded the same result

Comment: That's because the targetDensity was already set to that value. Also, my bad. I meant Bitmap.setDensity but you can also scale it with Bitmap.createScaledBitmap().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

Bitmap bitmapOrg = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), new  ByteArrayInputStream(imageThumbnail)).getBitmap();

int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();

float scaleWidth = metrics.scaledDensity;
float scaleHeight = metrics.scaledDensity;

// create a matrix for the manipulation
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
// resize the bit map
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

// recreate the new Bitmap
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
```

Or

Maybe try a differnet approach... try setting the height and width of images in the XML layout in dips, I am guessing you have the ImageView with wrap_content height and width at the moment, try setting the height and width to 48dip

Comment: This resulted in an increase in size, but it is still smaller than the one loaded from the application resources: http://imgur.com/U6rLO

Comment: Yes, so you should deliver your images the correct size for a 480x320 screen, then the phone will upscale by x1.5 for example on a a phone of resolution 800x480

Comment: So basically, the image on the web needs to be bigger... the scales on phones are: LDPI: 0.6666, MDPI: 1, HDPI: 1.5

Comment: i deliver the exact same image as i put in my resource folder atm. This will be a thumbnail of the users avatar or picture, i will really only have 48x48 pixel thumbnails of it, i don't mind if the images strech a bit on large displays, but i need to find a way to make them the exact same size as the other 48x48 images i have

Comment: Maybe try a differnet approach... try setting the height and width of images in the XML layout in dips, wo I am guessing you have the ImageView with wrap_content height and width at the moment, try setting the height and width to 48dip

Answer (score 17):

you can trigger android bitmapfactory to scale bitmap automatically, codes for this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
options.inScreenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
options.inTargetDensity =  metrics.densityDpi;
options.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
in.close();
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bm);
```

Comment: This answer requires explanation of using `inScreenDensity`, `inTargetDensity` and `inDensity`.

Comment: In this point for scale

options.inScreenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
options.inTargetDensity =  metrics.densityDpi;
options.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;

this 3 lines resolve this problem.

Answer (score -2):

Get the current density of the screen and set the drawable to that density

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int density  =  metrics.densityDpi
myDrawable.setDensity(densityDpi);
```

Comment: where is densityDpi is define, which is set in this method "myDrawable.setDensity(densityDpi);"