# Save image to sdcard from drawable resource on Android

Tags: android, drawable, sd-card, android-image, android-button

I'm wondering how to save an image to user's sdcard through a button click. 
Could some one show me how to do it. The Image is in .png format and it is stored in the drawable directory. I want to program a button to save that image to the user's sdcard.

Comment: What kind of Image?  A photo that was just taken?  A photo from the gallery?  Something else entirely?  A little more detail is really necessary. If you posted some relevant code and described what you've tried it would really aid us in providing you help.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/android-bitmap-save-to-location

Comment: That is a good resource but could someone explain it a little , like where to put the code do i put in OnClick?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The process of saving a file (which is image in your case) is described here: [save-file-to-sd-card](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/save-file-to-sd-card.html)

---

### Saving image to sdcard from drawble resource:

Say you have an image namely ic_launcher in your drawable. Then get a bitmap object from this image like:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

The path to SD Card can be retrieved using:

```
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

Then save to sdcard on button click using:

```
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "ic_launcher.PNG");
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
```

Don't forget to add `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Here is the modified file for saving from drawable: [SaveToSd](http://pastebin.com/KkZVK0vF)
, a complete sample project: [SaveImage](http://www.mediafire.com/?q2x4c3nd55597t4)

Comment: I want to save the image from a drwable folder not from online!

Comment: @IranianLIon that is even more easy. Say you have an image namely ic_launcher in your drawable then get a bitmap object from this image like:
  `bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);` and use the above code, I'm providing it in answer :).

Comment: Thanks sorry i was late didnt log on in a while

Comment: Im having trouble with the code, on File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "ic_launcher.PNG");
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();   All the outputs have an error could you help me the error is  "outStream cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: @IranianLIon here is the complete sample project: [Save Image](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?q2x4c3nd55597t4), use it.

Comment: Hey imran it works but when i add my set wallpaper button i get an error. could you give me a sample project with a save button and set wallpaper button PLEASE!!!!

Comment: woops my bad i didnt notice i did that,

Comment: Why does it save TWO copies of the image?

Comment: yes image will copy in sdcard but why it will heap memory in logcat

Comment: Is there anyway to save gif image??

Comment: Why dimension of png changed after saving? My orignal png in drawable is 180x40, but the image saved to internal storage is 540x120. Exactly 3 time height and width. Any clue?

Comment: @RishabhChandel  [if you get bitmap from a resource, then the bitmap dimension will depend on the phone screen density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417034/how-to-make-bitmap-compress-without-change-the-bitmap-size). Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048603/android-scaling-of-images-to-screen-density) one for scaling.

Comment: transparent Image becomes black.Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are no real solution on that question, the only way to do that is copy and launch from sd_card cache dir like this:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId);
File f = new File(getExternalCacheDir()+"/image.png");
try {
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), "image/png");
startActivity(intent);


// NOT WORKING SOLUTION
// Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + resourceId);
// Intent intent = new Intent();
// intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
// intent.setDataAndType(path, "image/png");
// startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Kotlin**, you can do like this:

```
val mDrawable: Drawable? = baseContext.getDrawable(id)
val mbitmap = (mDrawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
val mfile = File(externalCacheDir, "myimage.PNG")
        try {
            val outStream = FileOutputStream(mfile)
            mbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream)
            outStream.flush()
            outStream.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
```