# On sharing image in drawable folder

Tags: android

Sorry for repeated question. I searched a lot on the Internet, got a lot of links too. But none of it worked correctly.

I've an Image in a drawable folder. Wanted to share t via apps like Gmail, Messaging etc.
How's it possible?
I used the following code:

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.myImage));
```

But this stop the "com.android.mms" what to do?

Also, is any permission required to be added? Or am I missing out anything? Does this sharing work on Android 2.2, cause I'm testing on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to store your image to the internal/external storage first, then you can be able to share it by using Gmail, ....

[More info in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13584068/1876084)

Comment: I used shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myImage.png")); But it says, file Not found :(

Comment: Problem is that image doesn't get attached using this code, as you mentioned in link

Comment: Did you copy the image from resources to external storage first? Do you have correct path to that image?

Comment: Sorry, but how can that be achieved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10561536/1876084, you'll have to change the image name. Also you can see the whole code there