# saving gif file from drawable into phone sd? and remove it from sd after usage

Tags: android, drawable, gif, sd-card

I have been searching on how to save file from `Drawable` into sd card OR phone's internal storage. All examples such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558053/save-image-to-sdcard-from-drawble-resource-on-android) showed only for `PNG` type, I want to get `GIF` file from my drawable and save it into phone sd, and later remove it from sd after usage.

Anybody please help with the code? I appreciate it!

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: yeap. I have managed to do it! thanks for your answer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know there isn't such a native function on `Android` (maybe related to patent issues). You may try [this library](https://github.com/madmaw/animatedgifencoder/) for your purpose. Usually its meant to create animated `GIF` but a file with just one picture (frame) should also work.

So a complete example could be like this assuming you are dealing with a non animated `GIF`:

```
Bitmap someBitmap = [...];
File outputFile = new File("/sdcard/myNewGif.gif");
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (fos != null) {
    AnimatedGifEncoder gifEncoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
    gifEncoder.start(fos);
    gifEncoder.addFrame(someBitmap);
    gifEncoder.finish();
}
```

More examples by the library author can be found [here](https://github.com/madmaw/animatedgifencoder/blob/master/src/test/java/TestAnimatedGifEncoder.java).

Comment: It will display normal image see my code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/89115b12a61c8f99d784f628652cacc8