# Saving bitmap instance to SD card in .GIF format

Tags: android, bitmap, gif

I already decode a bitmap from someplace. I want to save it into SD card. But I found that Android just provides this `api(bitmap.compress(...))` for saving the bitmap in format jpeg or png.

I just want to save it as gif format.

Comment: Did you find out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer of alex  for the question in the following thread can help you?
[saving gif file from drawable into phone sd? and remove it from sd after usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126188/saving-gif-file-from-drawable-into-phone-sd-and-remove-it-from-sd-after-usage)

There is a library called "animatedgifencoded", which you should also use for saving one picture instead of an animated gif.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try to figure it out.