# Save Animated Drawable to GIF File?

Tags: java, kotlin, gif, android-drawable, android-glide

I am trying to make an image keyboard with the Android [Commit Content API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard). In order to implement this, I need be able to store `.png` and `.gif` files on the device and create file objects from them.

Currently, I am using the Glide library to fetch images from the internet. An example image I might fetch is [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vedantroy/image-test/master/Sad/sad1.gif). The Glide library provides me with `drawables` that contain animated GIFs. I need to be able to encode these drawables into `.gif` files that can be saved as files on the user's phone.

How can I do this?

I've looked at existing posts, such as this: [How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap), but they aren't helpful because the `Bitmap` object cannot store animated GIFs.

This post: [saving gif file from drawable into phone sd? and remove it from sd after usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126188/saving-gif-file-from-drawable-into-phone-sd-and-remove-it-from-sd-after-usage) also seems relevant, but, it doesn't explain how to turn an animated `Drawable` object into a list of `Bitmap` objects.

Also, it doesn't explain how to save a series of `Bitmap` objects as 1 GIF file.

Comment: Were you able to tackle this problem?

Comment: @sHOLE. Yes, I found the answer. I'll post it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you can save a `GifDrawable` from the Glide library as a file.

```
private fun gifDrawableToFile(gifDrawable: GifDrawable, gifFile: File) {
    val byteBuffer = gifDrawable.buffer
    val output = FileOutputStream(gifFile)
    val bytes = ByteArray(byteBuffer.capacity())
    (byteBuffer.duplicate().clear() as ByteBuffer).get(bytes)
    output.write(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
    output.close()
}
```

Comment: A java version please!

Comment: Can you explain why we need `duplicate()`? I remove that and it still works. Thanks!