# How to create BitmapDrawable from a file for different screen densities?

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, screen-density

Well know that if we put an image **96x96 pixel** in folder `xxhdpi` of project, it will be displayed in `32dp`.

Now I have an image file **96x96 pixel**, which is located on **storage**. I create a `BitmapDrawable` object from that image. All I want is: the image should  be displayed in `32dp`.

Here is what I tried:

```
BitmapDrawable bmd = (BitmapDrawable)BitmapDrawable.createFromPath(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
bmd.setTargetDensity(DENSITY_XXHIGH);
```

But it doesn't work. It looks smaller than `32dp`. Can anybody show me how to do it?

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8048735/6414107)

Comment: @SaravInfern thanks, but it doesn't work.