# Why Bitmap size change in different screen?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I Convert Text to Bitmap with this method:

```
 private Bitmap textToBitmap(String text)
{
    Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Typeface clock = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/myfont.ttf");
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setSubpixelText(true);
    paint.setTypeface(clock);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE  );
    paint.setTextSize(38);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
    myCanvas.drawText(text, 400, 30, paint);
    return myBitmap;
}
```

But in some of phone my bitmap is very small and in other its very Big
why that Happen?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but my guess is that what is happening here is the bitmap is not being drawn with device independent pixels, but rather actual pixels.  Hence, the size appears to vary depending on the resolution of the Android device you happen to be using.

Comment: `very small and in other its very Big` how do you know that? how you check it's size?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko  install my app on different phone

Comment: that won't show the size of the image. how do you know the size of the image, and where do you see that it is different? you show it, or how?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienkoi show it in Imageview

Comment: ok, so how you set a size of imageView?

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);//its unit is px, practical size of 1 px is different in various device.
```

You should resize bitmap according to device [scaledDensity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#scaledDensity), here is [a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048603/android-scaling-of-images-to-screen-density)